# Using div tooltips versus using g tooltips in d3

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

Say i wanted to add a tooltip to a chart i'm developing, i could use regular html elements like a `div` or i could use `g` elements inside the `svg` itself.

i would like to know what are the main differences between using div tooltips like so:

```
var tooltip = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('display', 'none');
```

and then move it around and modify it with

```
selection.on('someEvent', () => {
    tooltip
        .style('display', null)
        .style('top', mouseY + 'px')
        .style('left', mouseX + 'px')
        ... /* do what needs to be done */
});
```

or opt for a g element:

```
var tooltip = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
    .style('display', 'none');
```

and then translate it where needed using the transform attribute

```
selection.on('someEvent', () => {
    tooltip
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + mouseX + ',' + mouseY + ')')
        .style('display', null)
        ... /* do what needs to be done */
});
```

personally i like the g element a little bit more because looks a lot less like a hack, but it can be kind of clunky to manage what is actually *in* the tooltip.
So i'm really confused here guys, any help?

Comment: This question is *primarily opinion-based*. That aside, there is nothing hacky in using a div for the tooltip. It is very common, and it has the advantage of allowing way more flexibility (by using HTML).

Comment: I'm not asking what is the best way to do it, i just wanted to know what could be the pro and cons of both ways.
I'm not trying to start a war :)

Comment: I'm not saying anything about which one is the best, I'm just saying that the question is OT because it is opinion based. Second, I'm saying that using a div is not more hacky, as you stated in your question. Third, I'm saying that using a div is more interesting because it's more flexible: for instance when wrapping text, which you can easily do with HTML but not so with SVG. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Div

**Pros**

- Content is more flexible and responsive, large texts can be wrapped
- Tooltip can be showed outside of SVG

**Cons**

- Somewhat is hard to position on desired place

## g

**Pros**

- Positioning is somewhat easy
- It's content is  more solid , than div

**Cons**

- If you have tooltip of large size, part of outside svg will be trimmed
- Complex tooltip content requires more time